# Cookie, Local storage values are deleted in webview when Android device restarted?

Tags: android, android-webview

I m developing Webview based Android application, In my application storing some values into cookies and HTML5 local storage. I would like to know what is the different behavior for cookie and local storage for below mentioned 2 scenario's,since i don't have Android device with me.

1. Whether Cookie,Local storage values are deleted when device is restarted?
2. Whether Cookie,Local storage values are deleted when device is app crashed?
3. Whether Cookie,Local storage values are deleted when resume back after enters into background stack?

Thanks in advance 
~sri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Lifetime of cookie depends on how you defined the cookie. If you don't specify cookie lifespan it will be deleted as soon as browser is closed. If you do cookies should survive restarts and crashes
2. Local storage is for you to maintain, it will survive all your scenarios as well. Here's [good overview](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-html5mobile2/)